# I need to reset Xcode 6.3, or, maybe we all need to just use an earlier more stable version??

Tags: xcode6.3

I am running Xcode 6.3 and every time I try to start it it comes up with a spinning wheel, not the little color one which replaces your "mouse pointer" but a simple star/sun burst animation which seems to be trying to tell me that it is working on something? Is there a way to reset Xcode (other than the terminal commands that I have already tried: 
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode  AND: 
rm -rf YourProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdat

I am a newbe, and was trying something new, and I suspect that is what has put Xcode into this state. Tried to see what would happen if I made a new Workspace. Prior to that I was trying to figure out how to create a folder on my desktop to put my latest project in.

Comment: You can just uninstall Xcode & re-install it .

Comment: Thanks, I saw that coming, and I plan to go one better? and try the prior version too:)